# How to activate my lens on Quantal?

Tags: 12.10, unity, customization, lenses

How to enable/activate any unity lens on Quantal?

I installed many unity lens on Quantal, using the following command, but none is active on dash.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-wikipedia 
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-askubuntu 
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-help 
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-utilities 
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-answer
```

Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> it shows only app/file/music/video lens.

Comment: How did you installed them? From the software center or how?

Comment: sudo apt-get install

Comment: i saw a difference between gdocs lens and others on file name.lens; gdocs has Shorcat=g; the others have Visible=false and Shorcat=;

Comment: Can you mention **all** the packages that you installed in your question? You can find the last entered commands in your `~/.bash_history` file..

Comment: uciany@lap00:~$ h | grep lens | grep install
  452  sudo apt-get install unity-lens-wikipedia
  453  sudo apt-get install unity-lens-askubuntu
  454  sudo apt-get install unity-lens-help
  455  sudo apt-get install unity-lens-utilities
  462  sudo apt-get install unity-lens-answers

Comment: Have you added some PPA to install them?